# how to make argocd path to a branch instead of main in the git repo

Tags: github, yaml, argocd

I have the following:

```
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: Application
metadata:
  name: crm
  namespace: default
spec:
  project: default
  source:
    repoURL: <my url
    targetRevision: argocd
    path: argocd/

  destination:
    server: https://kubernetes.default.svc
    namespace: default

  syncPolicy:
    syncOptions:
    - CreateNamespace=true

    automated: 
      selfHeal: true
      prune:  true
```

This is working to connect argocd with the main branch, but what if I want it to follow a different branch instead?

Thank you.

Answer (score 10):

No, your example above will make the ArgoCD application load content from:

- repo: "<my url"
- targetRevision (**branch**): "argocd"
- path (ie. path in repo): "argocd/"
  meaning it won't load from main/master branch!

Use *targetRevision* to specify the branch you require if *source* is a Git repo URL.

See excerpt from the ArgoCD [application.yaml](https://argo-cd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/operator-manual/application.yaml) docs:

```
  # Source of the application manifests
  source:
    repoURL: https://github.com/argoproj/argocd-example-apps.git  # Can point to either a Helm chart repo or a git repo.
    targetRevision: HEAD  # For Helm, this refers to the chart version.
    path: guestbook  # This has no meaning for Helm charts pulled directly from a Helm repo instead of git.
```

Comment: The answer is correct, but the excerpt provided lists HEAD (a revision). It is possible to put a revision in `targetRevision` as argocd docs describe, whether HEAD or a tag or a commit hash. Those docs don't tell you that it can also be a branch name.